# Load fns into lein repl

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Hi I have some helper fns I want to load into the user ns for a lein repl on startup across all my projects.

What's the recommended way to do this as lein plugin?

Failing that I tried to make a ~/lein/user.clj and to my surprise that did't work? $Project/user.clj works fine but I don't want to copy to each project.

Comment: On my system, `~/.lein/user.clj` works just fine. Note the dot prior to lein (hidden directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [vinyasa](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa), which allows you to do exactly that.